# Exclude some Posts from count of tags

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-aggregation

I'm using [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to manage my tag.
I want to include a list of used tags with the indication of how many times each of them has been used. To do so I'm using [taggit_templatetags2](https://github.com/fizista/django-taggit-templatetags2) but I can avoid.

My `models.py`:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

My `template.html`:

```
{% load taggit_templatetags2_tags %}

  {% get_taglist as tags for 'blog.post' %}

  {% for tag in tags %}
    {% if tag.slug != 'draft' and tag.slug != 'retired' %}
      <h4 style="text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
        {{ tag }} ({{ tag.num_times }}) </a></h4>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But I want to exclude from the count all the tags of the draft posts and of the retired posts. I do not want just to exclude the tags 'draft' and 'retired' (I'm already doing that) but even the other tags that such posts can have. How can I do that?

For example I have two posts. The first one have only the tag 'dog'. The second one have the tags 'dog' and 'draft'. It's a draft, a post not yet publicated.

My code would give: dog (2) because it count the tags of all the posts. When a user will click on 'dog' it will appears a page with all the published post with a dog tag, so in our case one post because the second one isn't published. The user will ask himself: there are two dog posts, where is the second one? This isn't good. Also I don't want to hint the argument of the soon-to-be published posts.

Probably I have to mess with the `taggit_templatetags2` code...

To be honest it's difficoult for me to understand this code, also I think it would be better to don't change directly the original code or at the first update my code will be lost.

Here some code of `taggit_templatetags2`:

```
@register.tag
class GetTagList(TaggitBaseTag):
    name = 'get_taglist'

    def get_value(self, context, varname, forvar, limit=settings.LIMIT, order_by=settings.TAG_LIST_ORDER_BY):
        # TODO: remove default value for limit, report a bug in the application
        # django-classy-tags, the default value does not work
        queryset = get_queryset(
            forvar,
            settings.TAGGED_ITEM_MODEL,
            settings.TAG_MODEL)
        queryset = queryset.order_by(order_by)
        context[varname] = queryset
        if limit:
            queryset = queryset[:limit]
        return ''

def get_queryset(forvar, taggeditem_model, tag_model):
    through_opts = taggeditem_model._meta
    count_field = (
        "%s_%s_items" % (
            through_opts.app_label,
            through_opts.object_name)).lower()

    if forvar is None:
        # get all tags
        queryset = tag_model.objects.all()
    else:
        # extract app label and model name
        beginning, applabel, model = None, None, None
        try:
            beginning, applabel, model = forvar.rsplit('.', 2)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                applabel, model = forvar.rsplit('.', 1)
            except ValueError:
                applabel = forvar
        applabel = applabel.lower()

        # filter tagged items
        if model is None:
            # Get tags for a whole app
            queryset = taggeditem_model.objects.filter(
                content_type__app_label=applabel)
            tag_ids = queryset.values_list('tag_id', flat=True)
            queryset = tag_model.objects.filter(id__in=tag_ids)
        else:
            # Get tags for a model
            model = model.lower()
            if ":" in model:
                model, manager_attr = model.split(":", 1)
            else:
                manager_attr = "tags"
            model_class = get_model(applabel, model)
            if not model_class:
                raise Exception(
                    'Not found such a model "%s" in the application "%s"' %
                    (model, applabel))
            manager = getattr(model_class, manager_attr)
            queryset = manager.all()
            through_opts = manager.through._meta
            count_field = ("%s_%s_items" % (through_opts.app_label,
                                            through_opts.object_name)).lower()

    if count_field is None:
        # Retain compatibility with older versions of Django taggit
        # a version check (for example taggit.VERSION <= (0,8,0)) does NOT
        # work because of the version (0,8,0) of the current dev version of
        # django-taggit
        try:
            return queryset.annotate(
                num_times=Count(settings.TAG_FIELD_RELATED_NAME))
        except FieldError:
            return queryset.annotate(
                num_times=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items'))
    else:
        return queryset.annotate(num_times=Count(count_field))
```

where:

`queryset = manager.all()` gives a list of all the tags

`count_field` is a string: `taggit_taggeditem_items`

`queryset.annotate(num_times=Count(count_field))` is the queryset with an extra field `num_times`,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, here what I did, without taggit_template_tags2, probabily can be ottimized, you're welcome!

My `model.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

My `views.py`:

```
...
#filter the posts that I want to count
tag_selected = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug='ritired')
posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).exclude(tags__in=[tag_selected])
#create a dict with all the tags and value=0
tag_dict = {}
tags=Post.tags.all()
for tag in tags:
    tag_dict[tag]=0
#count the tags in the post and update the dict
for post in posts:
    post_tag=post.tags.all()
    for tag in post_tag:
        tag_dict[tag]+=1
#delete the key with value=0
tag_dict = {key: value for key, value in tag_dict.items() if value != 0}
#pass the dict to the template
context_dict={}
context_dict['tag_dict']=tag_dict
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context_dict)
```

My `template.html`:

```
  {% for key, value in tag_dict.items %}
    <h4 style="text-align:center"><a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' key.slug %}">
      {{ key }} ({{ value }})
    </h4>
  {% endfor %}
```

Fast and easy!

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to efficiently exclude items from a queryset, try using the **exclude** method on your queryset:

  queryset.exclude(slug__in=['draft', 'retired'])
- you can also try to use the **values** method to calculate the number of occurences of your tag. if I understood correctly, try:

  queryset.values('id').annotate(num_times=Count(count_field))

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm afraid your code can't help me now. I'm working with two external app (taggit and taggit_templatetag) so I don't know where to find the queryset or how to intercept them. Also to exclude efficiently those tags from the tags queryset is useful but my priority is to exclude the post with those tags from the post queryset used to count the tags... if I can do this I don't need to count myself the tags, taggit_templatetag will do for me. Yet if I will decide to do not use this app your code wil be useful. I edited my post to add an example